# The expectation value of intersecting particles

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, astrophysics, astronomy

If I have a light beam (a straight line)

it goes through a box of dust, which has travelling length $l$, dust molecule cross section $\sigma$, dust number density $n$.

how to calculate the **expectation value** of `the number of dust particles that will be intersected by the line of sight`?

my book says it is just $\tau = n\sigma l$ (which is also called the optical depth) but **why**?